# buttons to activate buttons that toggle from one div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apologies in advance if this is a simple trick, but I'm not any good at javascript so I don't know how to do it...

I have two buttons (blue and yellow) that toggle between two divs with content. On another part of the page, I have another two buttons (also blue and yellow) that are supposed to activate the same-colored button of these two toggle buttons. So blue will activate toggle-blue and yellow will activate toggle-yellow. I used the below script I found on here for the toggle feature:

```
<div class="flr-wrap">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="button active" data-rel="#content-a" href="#">a button</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="button" data-rel="#content-b" href="#">b button</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="flr-inner">
        <div class="container" id="content-a">AAA</div>
        <div class="container" id="content-b">BBB</div>
    </div>
</div>

// set content on click
$('.button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setContent($(this));
});

// set content on load
$('.button.active').length && setContent($('.button.active'));

function setContent($el) {
    $('.button').removeClass('active');
    $('.container').hide();

    $el.addClass('active');
    $($el.data('rel')).show();
}
```

from here:
 [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyEq7/)

What do I add to make the other two buttons trigger the active states of their corresponding toggle buttons?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: By activating, do you mean that original buttons are deactivated by default and enabled for clicking only after clicking on the second set of buttons?

Comment: no, the toggle buttons can be independently activated. the default is yellow-toggle in active state and then you can click on blue-toggle to activate it. the second set of buttons are on another section of the page and will scroll down to the toggle buttons when clicked, with the corresponding toggle-button activated

Comment: it's like two sets of buttons controlling the same toggle feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do pretty much the same, just use the selector based on your data-rel to add the active class and add the active class to the button's data-rel statement, like that it's quite easy to always toggle the matching tags

```js
function setContent($el) {
  var rel = $el.data('rel');
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.container').hide();
  $('[data-rel="' + rel + '"]').addClass('active');
  $(rel).show();
}

$(function() {
  // the right place to fire the initial setContent (all scripts are ready and page is loaded)
  setContent($('.button.active'));

  // add event handlers in ready event (DOM is most surely there)
  $('.button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setContent($(this));
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: none;
}
.button.active {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flr-wrap">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="button active" data-rel="#content-a" href="#">a button</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="button" data-rel="#content-b" href="#">b button</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="flr-inner">
    <div class="container" id="content-a">
      AAA
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="content-b">
      BBB
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="button active" data-rel="#content-a" href="#">a button</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="button" data-rel="#content-b" href="#">b button</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: oh that looks easy! let me try

Comment: I tried your method and it works, but only halfway: clicking on the yellow button will activate the yellow-toggle but clicking on the blue button does not activate the blue-toggle, it stays at yellow-toggle. when I activate blue-toggle independently and go back up to the yellow button and click that, it will deactivate blue-toggle and activate yellow-toggle. But the blue button doesn't work that way.

Comment: I had to revert to this method because I couldn't figure out how to add the css arrow to the button using the other method because the active class shifted to the div. I got this to work ok now, so thank you!

Comment: @isabel018 You are welcome (and if you could send me a link to jsfiddle with an updated version, i could see what i did wrong :)) (or if you update your post)

Comment: you didn't do anything wrong, I made a typo that's why it didn't work the first time I tried it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you need the second set of buttons to trigger actions of the first set, this means that buttons do the same thing.
Here's an example of how this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/ivanbatic/b43m405x/

Javascript:

```
$('.activator').on('click', function () {
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $('.panel').removeClass('active');
    $(target).toggleClass('active');
});
```

HTML

```
<section>
    <button class="activator" data-target=".panel-a">Blue</button>
    <button class="activator" data-target=".panel-b">Yellow</button>
<section>
    <div class="panel active panel-a">First Panel</div>
    <div class="panel panel-b">Second Panel</div>
</section>
<section>
    <button class="activator" data-target=".panel-a">Blue</button>
    <button class="activator" data-target=".panel-b">Yellow</button>
</section>
```

Also, you are not using buttons in your example, you are using links. Links are meant to take you to another page, buttons are meant to trigger an action.
If you want buttons to look like plain text, use CSS for styling.

Comment: yes, that is exactly how I want it! -- except blue-toggle has to be active by default on loading the page. I'm aware the example doesn't show buttons but I've modified it to use buttons, I just used the existing jfiddle as the example cos it was already there. apologies if that was confusing!

Comment: Ok, so you can just set the first panel to be active by default by adding the "active" class. I've updated the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: OK it all now works the way I wanted it to, so thank you! I've only one minor issue now -- I had added a css triangle under the active toggle using ::after and now that's not working. something else I now have to figure out!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I actually had added the following css to the example fiddle I gave above to make the triangles show: 

`.button.active { position:relative; background-color:#ffba00; } .button.active::after { top: 100%; left: 45%; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; border-color: rgba(255, 186, 0, 0); border-top-color: #ffba00; border-width: 12px; margin-left: -12px; }`

now I can't figure out where to add it to when I used your code cos the active class shifted to the div instead of the button